# Flutter windows Build, How to get pfx certificate for Microsoft store

Tags: flutter, windows, pfx, flutter-windows, microsoft-store

Im trying to take the build the for windows in flutter, using msix package. How ever after adding building the app , and when installing certificate it throws error as follows..

- Is this because the certificate expired?
- If it is expired how can i create a new certificate for it?
- Or is it because of any other issues?

[image]